# Frama-C Graph of Full File

Tags: c, graph, dot, frama-c

I have been trying to use the pdg-dot plugin to help create a good graph of my software.The problem is different files don't have main so Frama-C complains. When I use the -main tag and specify a function to start it, it only creates a .dot file for the function and anything inside of it. Is there a way to make a .dot file of the entire .c file I have?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Each generated PDG represents one function only. But you can get the PDGs for all functions that are reachable from the entry point (main).

Comment: I have a good entry point but now, after I had to fight with the missing header files, I get gtkwin.c:77:[kernel] user error: syntax error. Anything I can do to fix this?